# Convert php array into a comma separated list of strings

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following array:

```
$arr = [
    0 => 'value1',
    1 => 'value2',
    2 => 'value3'
];
```

The select function of my db class takes arguments in the following format:

```
DB::table('users')->select('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

How can I convert my array to pass those values in my select function?

I tried `implode(',', $arr)` and it gives one string with comma separated values, but what I want is not a single string, it's a list of comma separated strings like in the example above.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps `DB::table('users')->select(...$arr)` if you're using a modern version of PHP; or simply `DB::table('users')->select($arr)`, as the select method will accept an array of arguments

Comment: one solution: `DB::table('users')->select("'".implode("','",$array)."'")`

Answer (score 3):

`select()` can accept an array, so try:

```
DB::table('users')->select($arr);
```

This is [source code of `select()` method](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Query/QueryBuilder.php#L465):

```
public function select($select = null)
{
    ....

    // In this line Laravel checks if $select is an array. If not, it creates an array from arguments.
    $selects = is_array($select) ? $select : func_get_args();
```

Comment: It actually "prefers" an array, great!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Laravel 5.8 as follows:

```
DB::table('users')->select('username')->pluck('username')->unique()->flatten();
```

Hope this helps.